# Change "Group windows by application" preference using command line

Tags: command-line, macos

As per the title I'd like to configure the preference entitled

`Group windows by application` which is found in Preferences > Mission Control.

Most settings seem to have something like

```
defaults write com.apple.xxxx setting-name -bool false
```

But i can't seem to find one for this setting.

Answer (score 3):

The `defaults` *command* for **Group windows by application** in **System Preferences** > **Mission Control** is e.g.:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-group-apps -bool false
```

In older version, it used to be:

```
defaults write com.apple.dock expose-group-by-app -bool false
```

- The *value* can be `true` or `false`.

However, that will not immediately change it in the UI and it may get overwritten anyway.

The safest way to change it is from the UI.

Note: As suggested in the *comments* one can use `killall Dock` directly afterwards however, `killall Dock` will force all minimized windows to show, as well as it's visually disruptive. I'd suggest using AppleScript to change it as it will not force minimized windows to show nor it is as visually disruptive.

The following **AppleScript** *code* will *check/uncheck* the **Group windows by application** *checkbox* in **System Preferences** > **Mission Control**, and will not cause the same visual disruption that `killall Dock` will. It can be saved as an **AppleScript** *application* in **Scrip Editor**.

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set the current pane to pane id "com.apple.preference.expose"
    tell application "System Events"
        click checkbox "Group windows by application" of group 2 of window "Mission Control" of application process "System Preferences"
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```

Note; This AppleScript *code* was tested under macOS 10.12.5 and my need adjusting for some earlier versions of OS X.

Comment: You might want to follow that `defaults` command with `killall Dock` to restart the Dock process.

Comment: @IconDaemon, Yes one can do that however `killall Dock` will force all minimized windows to show as well as it's visually disruptive.

Comment: On recent versions of macOS, the preference key has been changed to `expose-group-apps`.